# Pandas and Longs with Python

Tags: python, pandas, jira

Edit:

So i was doing some reasearch and ended up with this solution which worked.

```
converters = {col: str for col in (0,3)}    
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheetname = 'data',converters=converters)

for index,row in df.iterrows():
     jira = str(row['Numbers']))
```

I am attempting to read an excel file using pandas. One of the Values in my excel file is the number 1085879717972. When I read the file Panda is seeing the number in the column 'Numbers' as 1.08587971797e+12 Is there a way to read the number as displayed in the excel file?

```
xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(in_path)
df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheetname = 'data')

for index,row in df.iterrows():

    jira = str(row['Numbers']))
```

Comment: What happens when you add `converters={'Numbers': np.int64}` to your `read_excel()`?

Comment: @chrisaycock  I was just doing some research and i stumbled upon this solution as well. I actaully went with this  
converters = {col: str for col in (0,3)} 
 df = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheetname = 'data',converters=converters)
 As there are other columns that 
are not integers, but I can live with them all being converted to strings and convert to a number where necessary.